# Trying to have multiple domains direct to one domain; homepage works, but internal pages don't

Tags: wordpress, dns, multiple-domains

Basically, I have multiple domains; let's call them domain1.com, domain2.com, and domain3.com. I want domain2.com and domain3.com to direct to domain1.com. At the moment, they do, but only the homepage. If I click on a link that is domain2.com/page-2, for example, I don't get sent to domain2.com/page-2, I get sent to domain2.com/page-2.

I've set up the DNS for domains domain2.com and domain3.com with an A record, directed to the ip address of the server the website is on (cloudways), and a CNAME with the following values:

Host name: [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)
Type: CNAME
Data: domain1.com

Comment: "If I click on a link that is domain2.com/page-2, for example, I don't get sent to domain2.com/page-2, I get sent to domain2.com/page-2" - this seems like the desired action based on your description. Maybe you can rephrase the issue?